# Advanced filter and reducing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm receiving this JSON from my API, I'm trying to transform it into a usable format for my form ( it will be a list with checkbox)

```
{
  "uuid": "daff25b9-1efa-4c25-904f-7bf08bf22ce6",
  "concrete_samples": [
    {
      "uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
      "sample_datetime": "2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00",
      "sample_specimens": {
        "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100": [
          {
            "uuid": "4a730dd7-7bdb-4671-9b28-9b107759f4c8",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "321"
          },
          {
            "uuid": "205e31dd-637e-4588-bfbe-25093ff2c0cc",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "322"
          },
          {
            "uuid": "c9f975a9-b152-4711-b103-bda63e6e9d0b",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "323"
          },
          {
            "uuid": "c88940e4-28aa-4e64-b6b9-854a67797a7c",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "324"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the format im trying to transform it into is the below

```
[
{
  "type": "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100",
  "sample_datetime": "2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00",
  "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
  "mould_number": "321"
},
{
  "type": "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100",
  "sample_datetime": "2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00",
  "sample_uuid": "205e31dd-637e-4588-bfbe-25093ff2c0cc",
  "mould_number": "322"
},
{
  "type": "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100",
  "sample_datetime": "2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00",
  "sample_uuid": "c9f975a9-b152-4711-b103-bda63e6e9d0b",
  "mould_number": "323"
},
{
  "type": "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100",
  "sample_datetime": "2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00",
  "sample_uuid": "c88940e4-28aa-4e64-b6b9-854a67797a7c",
  "mould_number": "324"
}]
```

I've been stumped on this for several hours and i just cannot wrap my head around filtering and reducing this. If someone could light the path a little i'm sure i could figure it out. There can be multiple concrete_samples and the concrete_compressive_cylinder_100 can be null additionally the sample_specimens can also be null ( if there are no specimens attached to the sample )

I've tried this below but it just gives me an array of all the keys

```
let TempArray = Object.keys(res.data);
TempArray.reduce(function(concreteCylinderArray, sampleDateTime, sampleUUID, mouldNumber) {
  // now access this values from apiResponse and start setting them as the argument variables I have wrote
  const sampleObject = { concreteCylinderArray, sampleDateTime, sampleUUID, mouldNumber };
  return [].push(sampleObject);
}, []);
```

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/hmbydp3x/ The main takeaway is that you're going to be transforming one array into another, so the important function is `map()`

Comment: @ChrisG Thankyou excellent, working exactly how I need it to. 

I will study this answer to figure out how to do it on my own in future.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` over the `concrete_samples` grabbing the time and type, and then `map` over the `specimens` array returning new objects containing all the relevant properties.

```js
const data = {"uuid":"daff25b9-1efa-4c25-904f-7bf08bf22ce6","concrete_samples":[{"uuid":"bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433","sample_datetime":"2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00","sample_specimens":{"concrete_compressive_cylinder_100":[{"uuid":"4a730dd7-7bdb-4671-9b28-9b107759f4c8","sample_uuid":"bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433","mould_number":"321"},{"uuid":"205e31dd-637e-4588-bfbe-25093ff2c0cc","sample_uuid":"bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433","mould_number":"322"},{"uuid":"c9f975a9-b152-4711-b103-bda63e6e9d0b","sample_uuid":"bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433","mould_number":"323"},{"uuid":"c88940e4-28aa-4e64-b6b9-854a67797a7c","sample_uuid":"bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433","mould_number":"324"}]}}]}

const out = data.concrete_samples.reduce((acc, sample) => {

  // Destructure the time and specimens array from the current sample
  const { sample_datetime, sample_specimens } = sample;

  // Use Object.keys to get the type
  // (always the first key assuming the data shape doesn't change)
  const type = Object.keys(sample_specimens)[0];

  // `map` over the specimens array, and combine the time and data
  // with the specimen-specific properties
  const specimens = sample_specimens[type].map((obj) => {
    const { sample_uuid, mould_number } = obj;
    return { sample_datetime, type, sample_uuid, mould_number };
  });

  // Concatenate that array to the accumulator
  // and return it
  return acc.concat(specimens);
}, []);

console.log(out)
```

Comment: what if there are multiple `sample_specimens` ? Sorry, but could not understand reason of putting first index [0]

Comment: Multiple `sample_specimens` wasn't specified in the question @BilalSiddiqui. Re your second question: `sample_specimens` is an object and the OP wanted the value of "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100". And the only way to get that is to grab the object keys (an array) and take the value of the first element.

Comment: I think looping over Object.keys(sample_specimens) would be better to consider all keys. For eg if there is another array with key  `concrete_compressive_cylinder_200`

Comment: Except that _wasn't_ in the requirements.

Comment: hehe, right !! but as a learner, I love to have a code that works for any number of arguments/keys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using nested `forEach` loops as follows.

```js
function convertFormat(input) {
  var output = [];
  input['concrete_samples'].forEach(sample => {
    Object.keys(sample['sample_specimens']).forEach(key => {
      sample['sample_specimens'][key].forEach(specimen => {
        output.push({
          "type": key,
          "sample_datetime": sample['sample_datetime'],
          "sample_uuid": specimen['sample_uuid'],
          "mould_number": specimen['mould_number']
        });
      });
    });
  });
  return output;

}

var input = {
  "uuid": "daff25b9-1efa-4c25-904f-7bf08bf22ce6",
  "concrete_samples": [
    {
      "uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
      "sample_datetime": "2019-10-03T12:11:00+10:00",
      "sample_specimens": {
        "concrete_compressive_cylinder_100": [
          {
            "uuid": "4a730dd7-7bdb-4671-9b28-9b107759f4c8",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "321"
          },
          {
            "uuid": "205e31dd-637e-4588-bfbe-25093ff2c0cc",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "322"
          },
          {
            "uuid": "c9f975a9-b152-4711-b103-bda63e6e9d0b",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "323"
          },
          {
            "uuid": "c88940e4-28aa-4e64-b6b9-854a67797a7c",
            "sample_uuid": "bb5d9b79-9e6b-4c21-9c1c-4771ce06e433",
            "mould_number": "324"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var converted = convertFormat(input);
console.log(converted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am late but apart from accepted answer this can be easy understandable solution.

```
const result = obj.concrete_samples.reduce((res, { sample_specimens }) => {
   let tempArray = Object.keys(sample_specimens);
   tempArray.forEach(key => {
      sample_specimens[key].forEach(data => {
         const sampleObject = {'type': key, "uuid": data.uuid,
            "sample_uuid": data.sample_uuid,
            "mould_number": data.mould_number};
          res.push(sampleObject);
      });
   });
   return res;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```